# Add nested properties to non existent properties using dot notation

Tags: javascript, object

In javascript, we can add new properties to an object using dot notation

```js
const obj = {}
obj.a = "hello"

console.log(obj) // prints { a: "hello" }
```

However, with dot notation it is not possible to add a property to a *not yet existent* object

```js
obj.a.b = "hello" // <-- cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'b')
obj.a = { b: "hello" } // <-- OK
```

I would like to achieve this behaviour

```js
const obj = {}
obj.a.b = "hello"

console.log(obj) // prints { a: { b: "hello" } }
```

### My Idea

The only thing i could think of which could get close to this, would be using a proxy

```js
const obj = new Proxy({}, {
    set(target, key, receiver) {
        // if a.b could make it here before the error is thrown, i'd handle this
       // btw, this means that "key" should contain [a,b] which is not how this works.
    }
})

obj.a.b = "hello"
```

The proxy idea cannot work and probably there is absolutely no way of changing JS's native behaviour like I'm asking but maybe I'm missing something instead?

Comment: Why would a Proxy not work?

Comment: a proxy won't work because `obj.a.b = "hello"` assignment will throw an error before the Proxy'd get a chance to be called

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A proxy *does* work. You need to use the [`get` trap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/Proxy/get) instead of `set`:

```js
const obj = new Proxy({}, {
    get(target, key, receiver) {
        if (!(key in target)) return (target[key] = {});

        return Reflect.get(target, key);
    },
});

obj.a.b = "hello";

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: Thank you! I knew I was missing something :)

Comment: This is great but it's a bit too permissive. `if (obj.a.b === "XX")` will add `{ a: { b: {} } } `  regardless, but it' clearly not desired. Is there a way to add the new prop only when it is part of an assignment like `obj.a.b = "hello` and avoid adding it if it's part of a conditional statement or something else?

Comment: @soffyo Afraid not. You don't get the context in which the get trap is invoked.